# How to fetch multiple values in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hope everyone is doing well! I'm trying to fetch multiple values using jQuery

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_quantity" placeholder="0">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_quantity" placeholder="0">
```

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var item_quantity = $('#item_quantity').val();
});
```

This would fetch only the first value. I'm trying to fetch all values. How to achieve this?

Comment: Use `$(".form-control").each(function(){ console.log($(this).val())})` . Also, you cannot use same id for mutliple elements .

Comment: don't use the same id in input field twice. The id is a unique element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=item_quantity]').change(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      console.log($(this).val())
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_quantity-1" placeholder="0">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_quantity-2" placeholder="0">
```